# NestJS, using typeorm on providers

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I want to make a provider which queries an entity from db. (what interests me actually is to make typeorm  available when I create a provider).
I get

```
[ExceptionHandler] Connection "default" was not found. - {"trace":"ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection \"default\" was not found.\n
```

I tried using service, using custom repository, nothing works. I have something like this in module:

```
{
      provide: MICROSERVICE_ID,
      useFactory: async (): Promise<Microservice> => {
        //ignore logic
        return await getRepository(Microservice).findOne(1);
      },
      inject: []
    }
```

TypeOrm is imported on app.module.ts

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => (configService.get('database'))
    }),
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by injecting Connection from typeorm.

```
import { getRepository, Connection } from 'typeorm';
{
      provide: MICROSERVICE_ID,
      useFactory: async (): Promise<Microservice> => {
        //ignore logic
        return await getRepository(Microservice).findOne(1);
      },
      inject: [Connection]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your database file. The Entity may not load as expected.
For newest NestJS version. We should load from ./dist/

Comment: it is working from inside the controller methods but not from provider

Comment: This problem happens once typeorm cannot connect to the entities. There are no repositories